# VB Script - Mailbox permissions finder

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, exchange-server-2003

I've come across the following setting and trying to figure out what an AceFlag value of 18 means, context is below:

```
dn = "LDAP://" & replace(rs.Fields("distinguishedName").Value,"/","\/")
    set objuser = getobject(dn)
Set oSecurityDescriptor = objuser.Get("msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor")
Set dacl = oSecurityDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl
Set ace = CreateObject("AccessControlEntry")

For Each ace In dacl
if ace.AceFlags <> 18 then
end if
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the ACE an inherited container ACE (0x10 + 0x02). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394063.aspx).